# ContextMenu with Static and Dynamically Loaded Items

Tags: .net, wpf, data-binding, contextmenu

I have a TreeView for which I am trying to make a ContextMenu.  The ContextMenu needs to have a couple of static MenuItems: "test" and "test."  It should also have a list of MenuItems within a MenuItem that presents the user with a list of dynamically loaded options (Binding to Parent.Parent.Children).

I can't figure out how to combine a DataTemplate with static MenuItems.  This is my best attempt:

```
<TreeView x:Name="SpatialHierarchyTree" DataContext="{Binding topContainer}" ItemsSource="{Binding Project}" >
<TreeView.Resources>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="moveContext" StaysOpen="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Parent.Parent.Children}">
        <MenuItem Header="Test"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Test"/>
        <MenuItem Header="List">
            <ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <MenuItem Header="{Binding Name}"  CommandParameter="{Binding Name}" Click="MenuItem_Click"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
        <MenuItem/>
    </ContextMenu>
</TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: bind ItemsSource only on MenuItem: `<MenuItem Header="List" ItemsSource="{Binding Parent.Parent.Children}">` ?

Comment: also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14489112/how-do-i-dynamically-bind-and-statically-add-menuitems

Comment: @ASh, your solution of ItemsSource on the MenuItem throws an error "InvalidOperationException: Cyclic reference found while evaluating the ThemeStyle property on element 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock'."

Comment: no idea what you are talking about; but as the one who has all the code in IDE, you can investigate

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `CompositeCollection`, e.g.:

```
<ContextMenu ...>
    <ContextMenu.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvs" Source="{Binding Parent.Parent.Children}" />
    </ContextMenu.Resources>
    <ContextMenu.ItemsSource>
        <CompositeCollection>
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs}}" />
            <MenuItem Header="Test"/>
            <MenuItem Header="List"/>
        </CompositeCollection>
    </ContextMenu.ItemsSource>
</ContextMenu>
```